# if else statement not working in loop #c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a, itemAmount, totalFee = 0, rate[10], fee[6] = {7, 3, 5, 2, 3};
    char item[6][50], inputItem[50];

    strcpy(item[0], "Rice Cooker");
    strcpy(item[1], "Radio");
    strcpy(item[2], "Iron");
    strcpy(item[3], "Charger");
    strcpy(item[4], "Kettle");

    printf("Amount of item: ");
    scanf("%i", &itemAmount);

    for(int a = 0; a < itemAmount; a++){
        printf("\n%i) Item : ", a+1);
        scanf("%s", &inputItem);
        strcpy(item[a], inputItem);

        if(item[a] == item[0]){
            rate[a] = fee[0];
        }else if(item[a] == item[1]){
            rate[a] = fee[1];
        }else if(item[a] == item[2]){
            rate[a] = fee[2];
        }else if(item[a] == item[3]){
            rate[a] = fee[3];
        }else{
            rate[a] = fee[4];
        }

        totalFee = totalFee + rate[a];
    }

    printf("\n%i", totalFee);
}
```

I want to add all of the items' rate at the end but when I run it, all of the items's rate are 7 instead of the following:

Rice Cooker: 7

Radio: 3

Iron: 5

Charger: 2

Kettle: 3

For example, if I enter two items, which are Radio and Kettle, the total rate went to 10. It is wrong because the radio(3) and kettle(3), should be 6 if they're added up.

I'm now learning array and I'm very new to programming please help me :)

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve]. In particular, replace input with hard-coded values and consider removing some of the products.

Comment: It is working, but `item[a] == item[0]` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: As @immibis alluded to in his comment, when you're checking `item[a]==item[0]` you're checking whether the memory locations are the same, not the strings themselves. The function you want is `strcmp`